# Post values from modal dialog partial view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, partial-views, actionresult

I have a view name "Edit":

```
@model EMMS.ViewModels.MaintenanceViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset style="width: 800px;">
        <legend>Maintenance Details</legend>
        <div class="editor">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipmentID)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EquipmentID, new { style = "width: 200px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EquipmentID)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="dialog-validate-user" style="display: none;">
        @Html.Partial("_ValidateUser")
    </div>
}
```

It contains a jquery UI dialog that populates with the partial view below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_ValidateUser";
}

<h3>User Verification Required</h3>
<p>Please enter your network login credentials.</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <div>
        <p>
            <span>User Name:</span>
            @Html.TextBox("UserName")
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Password:</span>
            @Html.Password("Password")
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

I want to pass the values of the UserName and Password inputs back to the Maintenance controller's edit (post) actionresult. The action result looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MaintenanceViewModel maintenanceViewModel, string UserName, string Password)
{
}
```

When I breakpoint the ActionResult, UserName and Password are always null. They are not part of a viewmodel, just parameters i need to pass to the edit method.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: In the generated HTML output, what are the actual names of your username and password textbox?

Comment: Here is the output:<form action="/Maintenance/Edit/223872" method="post">    <div class="searchDiv">
        <p>
            <span>User Name</span>
            <input id="UserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Password</span>
            <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

Comment: That looks right to me.  Are you able to verify that the data is in fact being sent from the browser?  Could you inspect the HTTP request to verify?

Comment: The request body using IE10 dev tools does not show the username/password: IsNew=False&RowID=223872&EquipmentID=00178&TaskID=152&DateCompleted=6%2F10%2F2013&ElaspedTime=30&RunHours=1.000000&LoadHours=2.000000&CycleCount=3.000000&Result=Pass&Void=false&Comments=dfsdfgsdf

Comment: btw, I intentionally left some of the view inputs out of the code I posted to shorten it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important:**

When you use jQuery UI dialog on that div, it's removing it from the form. That is why they are null.

You can see in my [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshthecoder/S654b/).

If I were you, I would separate out the forms so they aren't nested.

**Edit View:**

```
@model EMMS.ViewModels.MaintenanceViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset style="width: 800px;">
        <legend>Maintenance Details</legend>
        <div class="editor">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipmentID)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EquipmentID, new { style = "width: 200px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.EquipmentID)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
<div id="dialog-validate-user" style="display: none;">
     @Html.Partial("_ValidateUser")
</div>
```

**_ValidateUser Partial:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_ValidateUser";
}

<h3>User Verification Required</h3>
<p>Please enter your network login credentials.</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <p>
            <span>User Name:</span>
            @Html.TextBox("UserName")
        </p>
        <p>
            <span>Password:</span>
            @Html.Password("Password")
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string Password)
{
    // do something here with the login
}
```

The beauty of MVC is proper separation.

Keep in mind as well, the point of a custom ViewModel is to combine fields such as these.

**Additionally:**

After getting a little bit more information on what the requirements are, the best possible solution here would be to remove the form on the partial and add the Username and Password to the ViewModel :)

Comment: You mean have a different action result in the controller for the partial view? If so, I still need to pass the username/password to the edit methods post actionresult. basically, I have a requirement to reauthenticate a user before saving data and the user name must be saved with the data, kind of an audit feature

Comment: Yes that is what i mean. You could use separation like what I've shown or make the username and password part of the viewModel.

Comment: it appears the jquery ui dialog, for some reason, prevents the inputs from being included in the request. when I took the UserName out of the jquery ui dialog element, it worked both in the view model and as a parameter

Comment: just saw the info about jquery ui at the top of your post. That is my problem. Marked this as the answer...